# P4 Commandline Integrate and Resolve Problems

Tags: command-line, perforce

I use git a lot, but I am a newbie to P4 command-line.  I've used P4V, but do not have that option now.  I attempted to integrate changes from a staging branch to our mainline:

`p4 integrate //depot/working/staging/...@124466 //depot/mainline/...`

`p4 submit`

This brought up a `must resolve` issue with one of the files.

`Merges still pending -- use 'resolve' to merge files.`

So, I ran `p4 resolve`.  That gave me the options to merge, edit, etc.  I chose edit.  While in the edit screen, I hit some key-stroke that made the edit window close.  Now I'm stuck.   I cannot finish resolve-ing.  None of the commands I've tried seem to work:

`p4 resolve`

`p4 resolve -c 124570`  - the changelist created by p4 (?)

`p4 revert`  - to revert changes

`p4 revert -c 124570`

`p4 revert -c 124570 <the file>`

On all of these the cursor just sits there.  No action.

I tried running `p4 submit -c 124570`.  This gives me the `use resolve` message again, but that does not work.

Any ideas?  I do not know what else to Google on for this.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the editor process is still running in the background, and `p4` is waiting for it to exit so that it can continue with the resolve.

It would help to know what your editor is, but I'm going to take a wild guess that you're on a Mac and it's TextEdit, because it's a very common offender here -- click TextEdit in your dock and then go to `TextEdit > Quit TextEdit`.  (In the future you might want to `p4 set P4EDITOR=vi` or something else that will exit promptly when you close the file, as this plays much better with command line tools.)

If it's not TextEdit but you know how to use a command line, use your command line expertise on your platform to just kill the editor (`ps`/`kill` or whatever).

Failing all that, go back to that blinking cursor and hit Ctrl-C to just kill the `p4` process.  That'll work everywhere.  :P  When you `p4 resolve` again it should just pick up approximately where it left off (in whatever state it was able to record to the workspace and/or server before you killed it).

Comment: I had not thought of that.  I normally use vi/vim.  `I thought` I was in a vim window, but honestly not sure.  I have mapped key commands that differ slightly from normal vi/vim.  It may be that the editor was vim, but I hit a key-stroke pair that did not act as I thought it would.

Comment: Also, I've used `Ctl + c` several times to no avail.  :(

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Might be a server-side lock that was left around after the first resolve process terminated prematurely?  https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3163

Comment: Got it.  I closed all terminal windows - probably only needed to close the one - but it worked.  `p4 submit -c 124570` worked to show `use resolve`.  `p4 resolve` brought up choices for the editing again.  I'm in.   Thanks for making my brain think along that line.  `kill the window  kill the editor`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue, my config file, p4editor, port was right. Then also resolve command was getting stuck.

Fix: add the cl# with -c and resolve mode to automatic.

```
 p4 resolve -am -c <CL#>
```

am is automatic mode. For other modes please refer to:
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/cmdref/p4_resolve.html